# Whitespace after opening and before closing bracket of method/constructor declaration

Tags: java, checkstyle

I want to configure a simple checkstyle rule. It should ensure that there are whitespaces after the opening and before the closing round bracket of a method/constructor declaration.

*Examples:*

**VALID**: `public void validMethodDeclaration ( boolean foo ) {}`

**INVALID**: `public void invalidMethodDeclaration (boolean foo) {}`

Normal method **calls** should be like this:

`methodCall(true);`

The `ParenPad` and `MethodParamPad` modules are unfortunately not able to catch this case. `ParenPad` doesn't allow `METHOD_DEF` or `CTOR_DEF` as tokens while `MethodParamPad` can only ensure the space before the left round bracket.

Comment: Assuming you want the valid call to look like `validMethodDeclaration(true);` (no spaces), then it is impossible. The `RPAREN` token appears as the closing parenthesis on the definition as well as the call. You would have to write a custom check (possibly as a subclass of *ParenPad*) which allows making exceptions for certain parent tokens (such as `METHOD_DEF`).

Comment: Aw, I hoped that wouldn't be necessary, but alas. Will post the code for the custom check here when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

`ParenPad` will do this check for you. If you are interested in spaces after the opening and before the closing bracket of a method/constructor declaration, but you don't want them around method calls, constructor calls and calls of super, then you can run `ParenPad` twice with different set of tokens:

```
<module name="ParenPad">
    <property name="option" value="space"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="LPAREN,RPAREN"/>
</module>
<module name="ParenPad">
    <property name="option" value="nospace"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="CTOR_CALL,METHOD_CALL,SUPER_CTOR_CALL"/>
</module>
```

`METHOD_DEF` and `CTOR_DEF` are tokens that contain multiple other tokens in the tree structure, including normal `LPAREN` and `RPAREN`.

Comment: Thing is, that we don't want to have spaces within method/constructor calls, just in their definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and clarification. Hopefully my improved answer will help you.

Comment: Getting there - however now there's a false warning: for `methodCall(true);` I receive `')' is not preceded with whitespace`.

Comment: I'll look into it later today. I can make changes to Checkstyle if neccessary - will you be able to use Checkstyle 6.7 when it will be released? Or you are bound to the old version?

Comment: Suppose I can switch to the most current version. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You are right, with my solution there is unwanted warning on ')' in method call. Interestingly enough, there is no warning on ')' in cast operator.
Quick check in the code: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/1bd30555eac039d0486dffb3fc43b7a34117909b/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/whitespace/ParenPadCheck.java#L92-L93 - looks like someone excluded right paren from cast operator from this check, but forgot to do the same for method invocation. I'll propose an update to Checkstyle and will notify you about the progress. I have corrected code working locally.

Comment: Great, upvoting your answer in the meantime. :)

Comment: Thanks, here is issue to track the status: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/1058

Comment: Found out, that the above solution also forces whitespaces within conditional braces, like in `if ( a > 7 )` which isn't what we want. Same applies to Annotation parameter braces `@Annotation( "blabla" ).

Comment: Right... So probably we need new check/option in Checkstyle just for that. We cannot rely just on tokens.